# Drawing over a BufferedImage. repaint()

Tags: java, image, swing

I have a component on which I'm drawing a `BufferedImage` on all the surface.
I would like to draw something more over it, following the mouse when it passes over the area.
To do it, I'm adding a `MouseMotionListener` on the component and implement `mouseMove` method.  Inside mouseMoved method I'm calling `repaint()` at the end of the drawing of the drawing of the cursor image.  I would like to know if there is a better way to do it, cause the image following the cursor is really small, and I'm repainting every thing each time.

Comment: I edited your post by changing all the *"i m"* by *"I'm"*...  What is your concern?  That *repaint()* is not efficient or that the drawing you're doing inside the BufferedImage is innefficient?

Comment: Calling repaint each time to paint the all component is inefficient, my drawing next to the cursor is 1px wide and takes the whole height of the component.  My component on which there is a bufferedimage is 400px wide, so i was asking for better way to do it.  JLabel might be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add a JLabel containing an Icon to the panel with the buffered image.

Then when you move the mouse you just change the location of the label. Swing will repaint the last location so the buffered image shows through, then it will repaint the label at the new location. So let Swing manage the repaint.

Comment: The JLabel can be invisible or do i have to create one each time i enter the component ?

Comment: The problem with the JLabel is that i have to know the size of my component to do the icon.

Comment: @wotan2009, setVisible(...), setSize( getPreferredSize() )

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the coordinate of your mouse and the small image you gonna paint over your background, you can optimize like this [pseudo-code]:

```
void mouseMoved(event) {
  lastCoordinates = currentCoordinates;
  currentCoordinates = event.coordinates;

  image.repaint(lastCoordinates.x, lastCoordinates.y, smallImage.width, smallImage.height);
  image.repaint(currentCoordinates.x, currentCoordinates.y, smallImage.width, smallImage.height);
}
```

that way you only repaint the two regions you actually care about instead of the whole background.

Also, reading the javadoc it seems the code above my actually trigger 2 separate calls to painting stuff, which would be inefficient. You may want to try to pass in a 10 milliseconds   value or so to make sure the 2 paints execute together.

Check out javadoc for repaint() that takes 4 and 5 arguments:

- [4-argument](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) version
- [5-argument](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) version